# Best way to fix encoding UTF-8 in my function's package R

Tags: r, function, encoding, package

I try to deal with encoding UTF-8 my R package. My R version is **3.4.4** on **Windows**.

My package is composed of some functions with console printing and 
graph who needed encoding UTF 8 (french).

I try to add this line in my R Script (at the beginning of script containing  my function and in my function) but the printing is like this *"RÃƒÂ©partition de la diffÃƒÂ©rence"*

```
Sys.setlocale("LC_CTYPE","french")
options(encoding = "UTF-8")
```

In another script, after load my package, I also add this few line but I have the same encoding problem ...

Any ideas ?

Comment: What's the expected output?

Comment: if A is your column of names, then use Encoding(A) <- "UTF-8".

Comment: @OliverFrost: I would like to have in my outputs strings encoding like : **"Répartition de la différence"** and not "RÃƒÂ©partition de la diffÃƒÂ©rence".

Comment: @Prany : This is not a dataframe. Encoding refers strings print in console or text (title/xlab/ylab) in graphs.

Comment: Hi. Have you come across a solution to this issue? I also have packages which are heavy on non-ascii characters. Some rare times the installation fails and the letters get scrambled but then I try other ways to install and things work out fine. But would be good to know what the variables are.

Answer (score 3):

You can add a line specifying Encoding: UTF-8 in your DESCRIPTION file.

See https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-release/R-exts.html#Character-encoding-issues

> If the DESCRIPTION file is not entirely in ASCII it should contain an
>   ‘Encoding’ field specifying an encoding. This is used as the encoding
>   of the DESCRIPTION file itself and of the R and NAMESPACE files, and
>   as the default encoding of .Rd files. The examples are assumed to be
>   in this encoding when running R CMD check, and it is used for the
>   encoding of the CITATION file. Only encoding names latin1, latin2 and
>   UTF-8 are known to be portable. (Do not specify an encoding unless one
>   is actually needed: doing so makes the package less portable. If a
>   package has a specified encoding, you should run R CMD build etc in a
>   locale using that encoding.)

Please let me know if it solves your issue.

Comment: Thank's ! When I add this line that's fix the problem for print encoding in console but not for the encoding in graph (title/xlal/ylab). I don't understand how to fix encoding (in namespace) with your link.

Comment: What function do you use to plot?

Comment: I use ggplot function : `g<- ggplot(df,aes=(x,y)) + labs(title="Encoding UTF-8",y="Fréq")
print(g)`

Comment: you might need to escape those char? see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13819972/utf-8-in-ggplot-axis-labels and https://stackoverflow.com/a/38202460/1989480. i.e. need to add `options(encoding = "UTF-8")` to your `.onAttach` and `.onLoad` functions

Comment: there is no way to force encoding in title or ylab ? I also try to add `Sys.setlocale("LC_CTYPE","french")` but it doesn't work ..